# Alignment Issue in jquery mobile image Popup

Tags: jquery-mobile-popup

I have a div with id **popupBasic** for popup in Jquery Mobile

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
      <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img id="imgView" />
</div>
```

In order to Open the popup on a button click **btnViewPopup** following code is used.

```
function btnViewPopup() {
    try {
        if (localStorage.imageURL == undefined || localStorage.imageURL.length == 0 || localStorage.imageURL == "undefined") {
            Notify(22);
        }
        else {
            var source = localStorage.imageURL
            $("#imgView").attr('src', source);
            $("#popupBasic").popup("open");
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
    ErrorMessageDB("Issue Attachments", "btnAttViewClick", "", "click-to view attachment", err.message, localStorage.EmployeesKId4LastModifiedBy);
    }
}
```

Current implementation

1. there is a radiobutton list for list of images.
2. if select one its image URL will be stored in local storage.
3. When click View Button, set **src** of the **imgView**  with the value in localstorage
4. Call Popup("Open")

My problem is first time when i click View button,image displayed is small and it is aligned to middle right. next time when i open another or same image it is displaying full as i expected.
i did not given height and width for image, as it may be different for different images.

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your popup is being shown before knowing the image dimensions. You can open the popup after the image is loaded, as follows:

- **CSS:**

  ```
  #imgView
  {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  ```
- **JS:**

  ```
  function btnViewPopup() {
      localStorage.imageURL = 'http://www.elated.com/res/Image/articles/development/javascript/jquery/jquery-mobile-what-can-it-do-for-you/themes.jpg';

      try {
          if (localStorage.imageURL == undefined || localStorage.imageURL.length == 0 || localStorage.imageURL == "undefined") {
              Notify(22);
          }
          else {
              var source = localStorage.imageURL;
              $("#imgView").attr('src', source);

              $("#imgView").one("load", function() {
                  $("#popupBasic").popup("open");
              }).each(function() {
                  if (this.complete) {
                      $(this).load();
                  }
              });
          }
      }
      catch (err) {
          ErrorMessageDB("Issue Attachments", "btnAttViewClick", "", "click-to view attachment", err.message, localStorage.EmployeesKId4LastModifiedBy);
      }
  }
  ```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rosberglinhares/w20t0g39/).